# Need help interpreting panel specification

Tags: electrical-panel

On my electric panel spec sheet it says:

> Sum of current ratings of two breaker poles fed from one connector must not exceed 125 Amps.

What does that mean?

[image: Picture of the panel spec sheet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What they mean by this is known as a *stab rating*

What they mean by "connector" here is the tabs, or "stabs", that stick out from the busbars and make contact with jaws on the breakers.  In other words, each bus stab on your panel can handle a maximum of 125A of load, which can be split however you'd wish across the breaker poles on each side of the stab.

For instance, if you had a 100A 2-pole breaker mounted in the two bottom left spaces, you are limited to 25A on each of the two poles across from it (in the bottom right spaces, in other words), which practically limits you to 15A and 20A circuits as there just isn't that much that runs on a 25A breaker.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Quick off-topic question, I called my utility and they said my service is a single 120/240, am I right to assume that simply means single phase three wire (I think it is called Edison system) and has nothing to do with maximum load (Amperage).

Comment: @Chris -- you are indeed correct :)

Comment: Thanks again, your responses has been very helpful.